# Having updated Firebase from 2.x to 3.x, firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect('facebook') no longer works

Tags: authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

Having updated Firebase from 2.x to 3.x, firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect('facebook') no longer works. Facebook authentication used to work fine: it took you to Facebook to authorize logging in, then back to the Firebase web-app now logged in.

This is what happens now:

- The URL redirects to something like

> https://project-PROJECTID/__/auth/handler?apiKey=APIKEY&appName=%5BDEFAULT%5D&authType=signInViaRedirect&providerId=facebook.com&redirectUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&v=3.6.9

- Chrome's main browser window shows

> This site can’t be reached
>
> project-PROJECTID’s server DNS address could not be found.

- and the console reads

> [https://project-PROJECTID/**/auth/handler?apiKey=APIKEY_**](https://project-PROJECTID/__/auth/handler?apiKey=APIKEY_)…iderId=facebook.com&redirectUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&v=3.6.9:1
>   GET
>   [https://project-PROJECTID//auth/handler?apiKey=APIKEY](https://project-PROJECTID/__/auth/handler?apiKey=APIKEY)…oviderId=facebook.com&redirectUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&v=3.6.9
>   net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

It gets stuck there and doesn't automatically return to the Firebase web-app. Manually returning shows you still logged out.

Any ideas what may be going on?

Answer (score 0):

The call signature has changed:

```
var facebook = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
facebook.addScope('user_birthday'); // optional
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(facebook);
```

See [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login) for more details.

**Edit:** In addition, it looks like you may be initializing the SDK wrong. Can you show me what `firebase.initializeApp` looks like in your app?

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I'm actually using Rebase rather than Firebase directly, so the command I was using is [this](https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base#authwithoauthredirectprovider-handler-settings). I should have stated it in the question but there were no replies when worded in terms of re-base. Apologies. Correspondingly, this is the initialization code. Using the 1.x version it worked and updating rebase to 2.x and Firebase to 3.x simultaneously (with code changes shown [here](https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base#upgrading-to-re-base-2x-from-1x)) caused the problem.